# Javascript function works when defined the object oriented way but not normally

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have the following code in a .js file in my wordpress library:

```
  jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){

        var timerLength = 5;
        var secs = timerLength;
        var currentSeconds = 0


        function countdownTimer() {
                      currentSeconds = secs % 60;
                      secs--;
                      if(secs !== -1) setTimeout('countdownTimer()',1000);
                      console.log(currentSeconds);
                      if(currentSeconds == "00"){
                          // Popup shows if the timer runs out
                          showPopup();
                      };
                  };

        function checkForCookies() {
                cookieValue = $.cookie('solium_product_page_notification');
                if ( cookieValue == undefined ){
                  countdownTimer();
                } else if ( cookieValue == "closed" || "dont-show-again" ) {
                  console.log('Cookies are blocking the popup');
                };
        };

        function showPopup() {
                  $("#productModal").modal("show");
                  setCookies();
        };

        function setCookies(){
                $("#close-only").on("click", function(){
                  $.cookie('solium_product_page_notification','closed', { expires: 1 }); // Cookie expires in 1 day
                  console.log('Temp Cookie Created');
                });
                $("#dont-show-again").on("click", function(){
                  $.removeCookie('solium_product_page_notification','closed');
                  $.cookie('solium_product_page_notification','dont-show-again', { expires: 365 }); // Cookie expires in 1 year
                  console.log('Perm Cookie Created');
                });
        };

      checkForCookies();

  });
})(jQuery);
```

and it is called in the footer.php here:

```
if( 'product' === get_post_type() ) {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
        ?>
                    <!-- PRODUCT PAGE MODAL -->
                        <!-- BEGIN MODAL -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="productModal" data-keyboard="false" >
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" id="close-only" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Hey there!</h4>
                                        <p class="popup-text">While you were looking around, we found a few things you may be interested in!</p>
                                        <button type="button" class="plain-link" id="dont-show-again" data-dismiss="modal">Dont Show Again</button>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END MODAL -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/product-modal.js"></script>
        <?php
    };

};
```

Now when the page loads it does the cookie check, then it starts the countdown, it console logs 5 but once it goes to count down to 4 I receive "VM1850:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: countdownTimer is not defined" in Chrome.

However, if I define countdown time in object oriented fashion

```
            countdownTimer = function() {
                      currentSeconds = secs % 60;
                      secs--;
                      if(secs !== -1) setTimeout('countdownTimer()',1000);
                      console.log(currentSeconds);
                      if(currentSeconds == "00"){
                          // Popup shows if the timer runs out
                          showPopup();
                      };
                  };
```

Everything works fine! Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening? I was wondering if the jQuery noconflict was causing the problem as all this code is wrapped in a function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: short answer is you are defining as global variable in second case, in the first case it only has scope within the `document.ready`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function is defined inside the document ready block and you call it on global scope in the setTimeout.

```
if(secs !== -1) setTimeout('countdownTimer()',1000);  //executes on window, not the current scope
```

needs to be

```
if(secs !== -1) setTimeout(countdownTimer,1000);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Not sure if I overlooked that or just didnt realize it!